# How to extract a live youtube chat information?

Tags: youtube, extract, live

I'm aware that google has an api for youtube live chat and statistics, but to avoid all the auth and tokens, I'm looking for a much simpler solution to read and process the live chat messages, without the need to auth. This website is able to show the live like counter and views without the need to authenticate (https://youtubelikecounter.com)
Youtube has the option to open in a new window the live chat, and I think, by expecting the elements of that window, that there must be a simpler solution for that, I just can't find out how. Any suggestions?
I've been trying to get google auth to work, but it seems to be much more complicated than just reading the website information.

Answer (score 0):

Without any kind of authentification you can get the number of viewers of a live thanks to `item["liveStreamingDetails"]["concurrentViewers"]` https://yt.lemnoslife.com/noKey/videos?part=snippet,liveStreamingDetails&id=VIDEO_ID you can also access to the number of views and likes respectively in `item["snippet"]["viewCount"]` and `item["snippet"]["likeCount"]`

Then thanks to `item["liveStreamingDetails"]["activeLiveChatId"]` you can access in the same way the livestream chat: https://yt.lemnoslife.com/noKey/liveChat/messages?part=snippet,authorDetails&liveChatId=LIVE_CHAT_ID